# Is it possible to display an objects instance variables in IPython like Matlab does?

Tags: python, matlab, ipython

I'm trying to move away from Matlab to Python.  While the magic ? in IPython is nice, one very nice feature of Matlab is that you can see on the command line (by omitting the ;) the instance variables (called properties in Matlab) of the object in question.  Is this possible in python (I guess via IPython)?

Ideally a class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _x = 5

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x + 100

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value + 1

    def myFunction(self, y):
        return self.x ** 2 + y
```

Would display something like:

```
mc = Myclass()
mc
<package.MyClass> <superclass1> <superclass2>

Attributes:
_x: 5
 x: 105

Method Attributes:
myFunction(self, y)
```

Is that possible via overriding the print method (if such a thing exits) of the class?  Or via a magic method in ipython?

Comment: Try writing the object name followed by a dot, then double tap TAB, e.g. `myobj.<TAB><TAB>`. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: That seems to just list the instance variables and methods, which is close but not quite.  I'd like to see the values of the instance variables as well...

Comment: The way you've defined your property is odd—it's a per-instance property backed by a class attribute (`MyClass._x`)… until you first set it, at which point you create an instance attribute (`mc._x`) that shadows the class attribute. This behavior can actually be useful, but I suspect here it's a sign of confusion between class and instance members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no way to get a list of all attributes of an object in Python, because the attributes could be generated dynamically. For an extreme example, consider this class:

```
>>> class Spam(object):
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         if attr.startswith('x'):
...             return attr[1:]
>>> spam = Spam()
>>> spam.xeggs
'eggs'
```

Even if the interpreter could someone figure out a list of all attributes, that list would be infinite.

For simple classes, `spam.__dict__` is often good enough. It doesn't handle dynamic attributes, `__slots__`-based attributes, class attributes, C extension classes, attributes inherited from most of the above, and all kinds of other things. But it's at least something—and sometimes, it's the something you want. To a first approximation, it's exactly the stuff you explicitly assigned in `__init__` or later, and nothing else.

For a best effort aimed at "everything" aimed at human readability, use [`dir(spam)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).

For a best effort aimed at "everything" for programmatic use, use [`inspect.getmembers(spam)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers). (Although in fact the implementation is just a wrapper around `dir` in CPython 2.x, it *could* do more—and in fact does in CPython 3.2+.)

These will both handle a wide range of things that `__dict__` cannot, and may skip things that are in the `__dict__` but that you don't want to see. But they're still inherently incomplete.

Whatever you use, to get the values as well as the keys is easy. If you're using `__dict__` or `getmembers`, it's trivial; the `__dict__` is, normally, either a `dict`, or something that acts close enough to a `dict` for your purposes, and `getmembers` explicitly returns key-value pairs. If you're using `dir`, you can get a `dict` very easily:

```
{key: getattr(spam, key) for key in dir(spam)}
```

One last thing: "object" is a bit of an ambiguous term. It can mean "any instance of a class derived from `object`", "any instance of a class", "any instance of a new-style class", or "any value of any type at all" (modules, classes, functions, etc.). You can use `dir` and `getmembers` on just about anything; the exact details of what that means are described in the docs.

One even-last-er thing: You may notice that `getmembers` returns things like `('__str__', <method-wrapper '__str__' of Spam object at 0x1066be790>`), which you probably aren't interested in. Since the results are just name-value pairs, if you just want to remove `__dunder__` methods, `_private` variables, etc., that's easy. But often, you want to filter on the "kind of member". The `getmembers` function takes a filter parameter, but the docs don't do a great job explaining how to use it (and, on top of that, expect that you understand how descriptors work). Basically, if you want a filter, it's usually `callable`, `lambda x: not callable(x)`, or a `lambda` made up of a combination of `inspect.isfoo` functions.

So, this is common enough you may want to write it up as a function:

```
def get_public_variables(obj):
    return [(name, value) for name, value 
            in inspect.getmembers(obj, lambda x: not callable(x))
            if not name.startswith('_')]
```

You can turn that into a custom IPython %magic function, or just make a %macro out of it, or just leave it as a regular function and call it explicitly.

---

In a comment, you asked whether you can just package this up into a `__repr__` function instead of trying to create a %magic function or whatever.

If you've already got all of your classes inheriting from a single root class, this is a great idea. You can write a single `__repr__` that works for all of your classes (or, if it works for 99% of them, you can override that `__repr__` in the other 1%), and then every time you evaluate any of your objects in the interpreter or print them out, you'll get what you want.

However, a few things to keep in mind:

Python has both `__str__` (what you get if you `print` an object) and `__repr__` (what you get if you just evaluate an object at the interactive prompt) for a reason. Usually, the former is a nice human-readable representation, while the latter is something that's either `eval`-able (or typable-into-the-interactive-prompt), or the concise angle-bracket form that gives you just enough to distinguish the type and identity of an object.

That's just a convention rather than a rule, so you can feel free to break it. However, if you *are* going to break it, you may still want to make use of the `str`/`repr` distinction—e.g., make `repr` give you a complete dump of all the internals, while `str` shows just the useful public values.

More seriously, you have to consider how `repr` values are composed. For example, if you `print` or `repr` a `list`, you get, effectively, `'[' + ', '.join(map(repr, item))) + ']'`. This is going to look pretty odd with a multi-line `repr`. And it'll be even worse if you use any kind of pretty-printer that tries to indent nested collections, like the one that's built into IPython. The result probably won't be unreadable, it'll just defeat the benefits that the pretty-printer is meant to provide.

As for the specific stuff you want to display: That's all pretty easy. Something like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    lines = []

    classes = inspect.getmro(type(self))
    lines.append(' '.join(repr(cls) for cls in classes))

    lines.append('')
    lines.append('Attributes:')
    attributes = inspect.getmembers(self, callable)
    longest = max(len(name) for name, value in attributes)
    fmt = '{:>%s}: {}' % (longest, )
    for name, value in attributes:
        if not name.startswith('__'):
            lines.append(fmt.format(name, value))

    lines.append('')
    lines.append('Methods:')
    methods = inspect.getmembers(self, negate(callable))
    for name, value in methods:
        if not name.startswith('__'):
            lines.append(name)

    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Right-justifying the attribute names is the hardest part here. (And I probably got it wrong, since this is untested code…) Everything else is either easy, or fun (playing with different filters to `getmembers` to see what they do).

Comment: `inspect.getmembers(spam)` seems pretty close to what I'm looking for (other than the first 18 entries in the list).  Is it possible to override the print method for the class so I get the behavior described in the (newly edited) original question?

Comment: ...rather than an ipython magic function I mean.  So is there a way to make it the default behavior

Comment: Can I just write a superclass where I override `__repr__` to do what I've described and then make sure all my subclasses inherit from this superclass?

Comment: Yes, if you want a superclass to all of your classes, this is a great solution. You may want to consider overriding both `__repr__` and `__str__` so you can give, e.g., detailed internal information when just evaluating `obj` at the IPython prompt, but something more concise and readable when `print`ing it, but otherwise, sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with IPython (at least roughly) by implementing `_repr_pretty_`:

```
def get_public_variables(obj):
    from inspect import getmembers
    return [(name, value) for name, value in
            getmembers(obj, lambda x: not callable(x)) if
            not name.startswith('__')]


class MySuperClass(object):
    def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
        for (name, value) in get_public_variables(self):
            f = '{:>12}{} {:<} \n'
            line = f.format(str(name), ':', str(value))
            # p.text(str(name) + ': ' + str(value) + '\n')
            p.text(line)

class MyClass(MySuperClass):
    _x = 5

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x + 100
```

gives me out of:

```
mc = MyClass()
mc
Out[15]: 
          _x: 5 
           x: 105
```

clearly there is some fine tuning to be done in terms of whitespace, etc.  But this was roughly what I was trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You can get to an object's instance variable using `obj.__dict__`, e.g.:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


d1 = Dog("Fido", 7)

for key, val in d1.__dict__.items():
    print(key, ": ", val)
```

Output:

```
age :  7
name :  Fido
```

You might find this doesn't work well with real objects that might have a large number of instance variables and methods though.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to include instance variables declared between the `class Dog:` line and the `def __init__` line...

Comment: Of course this won't work for objects that don't use a `__dict__` (e.g., because they have `__slots__`, or they're implemented in C, or they have a base class that does one of the above), or objects that do have a `__dict__` but also have custom `__getattr__` and friends, or…

Comment: @user1507844: Those _aren't_ instance variables, they're _class_ variables. (But you're right, it won't show them.)