# How to inspect Python objects in similar way like JS objects in Chrome dev console?

Tags: python

In Chrome development console one can type name of a variable and output is a visual and interactive representation of the object. (In JavaScript objects are like dictionaries, so this is easy.)

I would like to have the same functionality in Python. I am shocked I cannot find anything similar. For example in IPython GUI console when I want to inspect variable `diff`, I get in this case its type instead:

```
In [5]: diff
Out[5]: <_pygit2.Diff at 0x1a69930>
```

This command inspect the variable, but output is chaotic for complicated objects (here the output is incomplete):

```
In [10]: inspect.getmembers(diff)
Out[10]: [('__class__', <type '_pygit2.Diff'>), ('__delattr__', <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of _pygit2.Diff object at 0x1a69930>), ('__doc__', 'Diff objects.'), ('__format__', <built-in method __format__ of _pygit2.Diff object at 0x1a69930>), ('__getattribute__', (...)
```

I think a live introspection is very useful when language has no typesystem. Maybe this functionality is available only in special Python IDEs?

**To show how it is done in Chrome:**

[image: example of Chrome devtools object introspection]

On the picture you can see an introspecion of variable `f`. It is an object of type `Form`, you can click on it and see its properties (e.g. `_meetingTimeFrom`) and theirs values, you can click further on properties to inspect them, you can see object's methods (e.g. field `__proto__`, this might be a way how to see object methods in JavaScript).

Comment: You get the `__repr__`, which isn't necessarily just the type (that's the default). Try e.g. `dir(thing)`.

Comment: You can iterate `diff`. By that line: `list(diff)`

Comment: @GeorgePetrov I do not want to iterate anything, I want an interactive introspection! ;)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your correction, but my point is that I do not get the object itself (its visual representation).

Comment: ...that *is* its visual representation.

Comment: Basically you have [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) the build in debugger. But that runs in text mode. If you want to have nice GUI debugging, you need to use a good IDE.

Comment: @KlausD. Are in pdb better built-in object introspection tools than in Python shell? Because I think pdb does not offer anything extra.

Comment: At least is allows you to add breakpoints and step through the code. It does not add much to the presentation.

Comment: @KlausD.  Thanks, but debugging is not what I am asking about. I have edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I found similar question that has very good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487839/is-it-possible-to-display-an-objects-instance-variables-in-ipython-like-matlab-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to list attributes in readable way, `pprint.pprint` is your friend:

```
from pprint import pprint
from inspect import getmembers

class X:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

x = X([42] * 5, [True] * 15)

pprint(getmembers(x))
pprint(vars(x))
```

> If you're interested in a GUI for this, take a look at
>   [objbrowser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objbrowser). It uses the inspect module from the Python standard
>   library for the object introspection underneath.
>
> [image: objbrowserscreenshot]

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23145626) by titusjan

Comment: Although this answer is sufficient for me, thank you for it, I would like to post again a link that is in comments bellow my question where are other interesting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487839/is-it-possible-to-display-an-objects-instance-variables-in-ipython-like-matlab-d